# Memory limit has been reached - magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

After migrating my magneto site to new server (CentOS 6 ) i can't update or upload new images to any of my products. its showing  **Memory limit has been reached** while uploading any images.

logs :

> 2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
> 2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
>   2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
>   2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For memory limit issue while uploading the product image, go to `lib/Varien/Image/Adapter` open `Gd2.php`

Now search for method `protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)` i.e

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
    if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
    }
    elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
    }

   return (int)$memoryValue;
}
```

Make the following changes in the above method like :

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
     /*
     if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
         return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
     }
     elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
         return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
     }

     return (int)$memoryValue;
     */
     return 2147483648;
     //1024*1024*1024*2 = 2G
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks worked perfectly. Thanks again ! Voted. Do you have any idea why product images are not showing in the frontend ?

Comment: Hi @SumithHarshan ! I'm glad I was able to help. For product images, you can check for directory permissions first and also check for memory limit. Please see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/recommended-magento-php-memory-limit.  Please let me know If you are still facing the issue...

Comment: Better option is to change PHP settings from using gigabytes (eg. 2G) to megabytes (eg. 2048M)